# Que veut dire Bernanos quand il écrit "il faut savoir risquer la peur" ?

Tags: sens

Que veut dire Bernanos quand il écrit :

> « il faut savoir risquer la peur, comme on risque la mort, le vrai courage est dans ce risque »

Le contexte est l'article [*Terrorisme : et si on avait raison d'avoir peur ?*](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/la-chronique-de-jean-birnbaum/terrorisme-si-avait-raison-davoir-peur) et j'ai l'impression qu'il dit qu'il faut risquer *d'avoir* peur mais je ne comprends pas trop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cette citation du [Dialogue des Carmélites](http://www.biblisem.net/narratio/berncarm.htm) peut se comprendre ainsi :

> Il ne faut pas nier la peur. Il faut accepter d'avoir peur, accepter et affronter le risque qu'elle induit.

L'action se situe dans un couvent du Carmel en 1789. On vient d'apprendre que le couvent va être dépouillé de tous ses biens par les révolutionnaires. Des exactions ont été commises contre d'autres lieux de culte. Blanche, qui aspire à rentrer dans les ordres, reçoit son frère qui s’apprête à quitter la France.

Elle se défend d'avoir peur :

> Vous me croyez retenue ici par la peur !

Son frère lui répond :

> Ou la peur de la peur. Cette peur n’est pas plus honorable, après tout, qu’une autre peur. Il faut savoir risquer la peur comme on risque la mort, le vrai courage est dans ce risque. Mais je vous parle peut-être ici un langage trop rude pour vous, un langage de soldat ?...

Answer (score 1):

Bernanos est, avec Sartre et Camus un des trois principaux acteurs de la naissance de ce que l'on appellera *Littérature du désespoir* voire *Littérature du nihilisme*

Ainsi *peur* et *mort* sont des mots qui ont des sens très particuliers avec Bernanos. (Lire *La grande peur des bien-pensants* (entre autres))

Dans ce contexte, la *peur* de Bernanos c'est très précisément de l'*angoisse*. Celle dont Sartre dira qu'elle nait de la confrontation, rencontre de l'étant avec le non-étant. De l'être avec le néant.

Et c'est cette angoisse qui est fondatrice et moteur de production.

Je me permettrai donc pour tes besoins de compréhension de me *risquer* ;) à une (nécessairement mauvaise) reformulation de la phrase de Bernanos ainsi :

Il faut **oser l'expérience de l'angoisse**. Elle est semblable à celle issue de la confrontation avec la mort. Le vrai courage consiste à surmonter cette expérience.